# Обращение к классу DBhelper из другого класса (отличного от Main)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

При обращении из MainActivity все прекрасно, но при попытке обратиться из другого класса возникают ошибки.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...
    public Context mContext;
    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "smhome.db", null, 1);
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TECH_TYPE + " (" + TECH_TYPE_COL_ID + " INTEGER, " + TECH_TYPE_COL_TYPE + " TEXT);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TECH_VENDORS + " (" + TECH_VENDORS_COL_ID + " INTEGER, " + TECH_VENDORS_COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + TECH_VENDORS_COL_TYPE + " INTEGER);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TECH_MODELS + " (" + TECH_MODELS_COL_ID + " INTEGER, " + TECH_MODELS_COL_TECH_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER, " + TECH_MODELS_COL_VENDOR_ID + " INTEGER, " + TECH_MODELS_COL_NAME + " TEXT);");
        System.out.println("Таблицы созданы");
    }
```

Обращаюсь из класса DbUpd

```
public class DbUpd {
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    LinkedList <Data> list;
    Context cont ;
    public DbUpd (){
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        Data data = new Data(12, "Тест");
        dbHelper.AddOne(data);

        list = dbHelper.Getall();
        String text = "";
        for (Data d:list){
            text=text+d.id+" "+d.type+" \n";
        }
    }
```

В результате в строке  `dbHelper = new DBHelper(this)` ошибка:

> error: incompatible types: DbUpd cannot be converted to Context

Comment: вам надо в конструктор `new DBHelper(this)` передавать не `this`, а контекст

Comment: Все верно, но откуда и как например dbHelper = new DBHelper(dbHelper.mContext); тоже приводит к ошибке, но уже другой :  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.testsavefiles, PID: 10622
                                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.Context com.example.testsavefiles.DBHelper.mContext' on a null object reference in method 'void com.example.testsavefiles.DbUpd.<init>()'

Comment: На один файл БД крайне желательно открывать только один экземпляр хелпера, ибо одновременная запись в файл из разных мест может испортить данные. Поэтому хелпер обычно оборачивают в синглтон "репозиторий", который инициализируют на старте приложения, а в других местах обращаются к готовому экземпляру.

Comment: верно. ведь вы указали `  Context cont ;` но нигде его не инициализировали. плюс @woesss верно указал, что для БД желательно использовать синглтон. хотя даже это решение потребует от вас контекста.